# python tkinter combobox/button

Tags: python, button, combobox, tkinter

I just started to use python and tkinter, I have created a gui with two combobox and  'run' buttons which contain two different options 'SPMI' and 'RFFE'. What I want my script to do is, when I select different options and click 'run' it should run the SPMI.py or RFFE.py file.

Help please, Thanks

My code:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *



def callback1():
    os.system('SPMI.py')

def callback2():   
    os.system('RFFE.py')

class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
     def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
          self.var = StringVar(master)
          self.var.set(status)
          OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
          self.config(font=('calibri',(10)),bg='white',width=12,fg='dark red')
          self['menu'].config(font=('calibri',(10)),bg='white',fg='dark blue')

          b1_1 = Button(Dragonfly, text = "Run", fg='blue',command=callback1)
          b1_1.place(x=85,y=150)


         b2_2= Button(Dragonfly, text = "Run", fg='blue',command=callback2)
         b2_2.place(x=275,y=150)


Dragonfly = Tk()
Dragonfly.geometry('400x400+400+300')
Dragonfly.title('Dragonfly')
mainlabel = Label(text='Dragonfly Trigger Test',font=('calibri',(14)),fg='dark blue').pack()


mymenu1 = MyOptionMenu(Dragonfly, 'Select Protocol', 'SPMI','RFFE')
mymenu2 = MyOptionMenu(Dragonfly, 'Select Protocol', 'SPMI','RFFE')
mymenu1.place(x=40,y=100)
mymenu2.place(x=230,y=100)
m1label = Label(text='Frame Trigger',font=('calibri',(12)),fg='dark green').place(x=57,y=60)
m1labe2 = Label(text='External Trigger',font=('calibri',(12)),fg='dark green').place(x=240,y=60)

Dragonfly.mainloop()
```

Comment: Besides needing to `import os`, what is the problem?

Comment: It does not link the run button to the combobox, what I want is if I select SPMI and click run it should execute the the SPMI.py and if I select RFFE and click run it should execute RFFE.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.var.get()` to get the value of the combobox.
You can then use that value inside the callback to make the callback's behavior depend on the combobox's setting.

---

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess

class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.var = StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.config(
            font=('calibri', (10)), bg='white', width=12, fg='dark red')
        self['menu'].config(font=('calibri', (10)), bg='white', fg='dark blue')

    def callback(self):
        val = '{}.py'.format(self.var.get())
        print(val)
        # subprocess.call([val])

Dragonfly = Tk()
Dragonfly.geometry('400x400+400+300')
Dragonfly.title('Dragonfly')
mainlabel = Label(text='Dragonfly Trigger Test', font=('calibri', (14)),
                  fg='dark blue').pack()

mymenu1 = MyOptionMenu(Dragonfly, 'Select Protocol', 'SPMI', 'RFFE')
b1_1 = Button(Dragonfly, text="Run", fg='blue', command=mymenu1.callback)
b1_1.place(x=85, y=150)

mymenu2 = MyOptionMenu(Dragonfly, 'Select Protocol', 'SPMI', 'RFFE')
b2_2 = Button(Dragonfly, text="Run", fg='blue', command=mymenu2.callback)
b2_2.place(x=275, y=150)

mymenu1.place(x=40, y=100)
mymenu2.place(x=230, y=100)
m1label = Label(text='Frame Trigger', font=('calibri', (12)),
                fg='dark green').place(x=57, y=60)
m1labe2 = Label(text='External Trigger', font=('calibri', (12)),
                fg='dark green').place(x=240, y=60)

Dragonfly.mainloop()
```

---

By the way, building a GUI with `place` is easy at first, but cumbersome in the end. For one thing, as it grows it become harder and harder to change the layout since inserting a new widget will tend to require fiddling with hard-coded coordinates all over the place. Another problem is that the widget layout fails to adjust to changes in window size.

For those reasons, people tend to use `pack` or `grid` to layout widgets:

```
import sys
import Tkinter as tk
import subprocess

class MyOptionMenu(tk.OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.var = tk.StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        tk.OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.config(
            font=('calibri', (10)), bg='white', width=12, fg='dark red')
        self['menu'].config(font=('calibri', (10)), bg='white', fg='dark blue')

    def callback(self):
        val = '{}.py'.format(self.var.get())
        print(val)
        # subprocess.call([val])

Dragonfly = tk.Tk()
Dragonfly.geometry('400x400+400+300')
Dragonfly.title('Dragonfly')
Dragonfly.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
Dragonfly.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  
mainlabel = tk.Label(text='Dragonfly Trigger Test', font=('calibri', (14)),
                  fg='dark blue').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)

mymenu1 = MyOptionMenu(Dragonfly, 'Select Protocol', 'SPMI', 'RFFE')
mymenu1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=10,)
b1_1 = tk.Button(Dragonfly, text="Run", fg='blue', command=mymenu1.callback)
b1_1.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=10,)

mymenu2 = MyOptionMenu(Dragonfly, 'Select Protocol', 'SPMI', 'RFFE')
mymenu2.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10,)
b2_2 = tk.Button(Dragonfly, text="Run", fg='blue', command=mymenu2.callback)
b2_2.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=10,)

m1label = tk.Label(text='Frame Trigger', font=('calibri', (12)),
                fg='dark green').grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10,)
m1labe2 = tk.Label(text='External Trigger', font=('calibri', (12)),
                fg='dark green').grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10,)

Dragonfly.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks it helped but it wont run my python scripts SPMI.py or RFFE.py

Comment: no worries I just replaced  print(val)  with execfile(val) but thank u for ur help.